# BIRT Error : Unable to determine the default workspace location in Java

Tags: java, birt

I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine the default workspace location.  Check your OSGi-less platform configuration of the plugin or datatools workspace path.
```

which makes little sense.

Reports are created using the BIRT designer within Eclipse, and we are using code to covert the reports in to PDF.

the code looks something like

```
    final EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig();
    config.setBIRTHome("./birt");
    Platform.startup(config);
    final IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform
            .createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);

    final HTMLRenderOption ho = new HTMLRenderOption();
    ho.setImageHandler(new HTMLCompleteImageHandler());
    config.setEmitterConfiguration(RenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML, ho);
    // Create the engine.
    this.engine = factory.createReportEngine(config);
    final IReportRunnable report = this.engine.openReportDesign(reportName);
    final IRunAndRenderTask task = this.engine.createRunAndRenderTask(report);
    final RenderOption options = new HMTLRenderOption();
    options.setOutputFormat(HTMLRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF);
    options.setOutputFormat("pdf");
    final String output = reportName.replaceFirst(".rptdesign", ".xls");
    final String output = name.replaceFirst(".rptdesign", "." + HTMLRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF);
    options.setOutputFileName( outputReporttName);
    task.setRenderOption(options);


    // Run the report.
    task.run();
```

but it seems during the *task.run()* method, the system throws the error.

This needs to be able to run standalone, without the need of eclipse, and hopped thatt he setting of BIRT home would make it happy, but these seems to be some other connection profile i am unaware of and probably don't need.

The full error :

```
07-Jan-2013 14:55:31 org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectivityPlugin log
SEVERE: Unable to determine the default workspace location.  Check your OSGi-less      platform configuration of the plugin or datatools workspace path.
07-Jan-2013 14:55:31 org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask handleFatalExceptions
SEVERE: An error happened while running the report. Cause:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine the default workspace location.  Check your OSGi-less platform configuration of the plugin or datatools workspace path.
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectivityPlugin.getDefaultStateLocation(ConnectivityPlugin.java:155)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectivityPlugin.getStorageLocation(ConnectivityPlugin.java:191)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfileMgmt.getStorageLocation(ConnectionProfileMgmt.java:1060)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile.internal.OdaProfileFactory.defaultProfileStoreFile(OdaProfileFactory.java:170)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile.OdaProfileExplorer.defaultProfileStoreFile(OdaProfileExplorer.java:138)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile.OdaProfileExplorer.loadProfiles(OdaProfileExplorer.java:292)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile.OdaProfileExplorer.getProfileByName(OdaProfileExplorer.java:537)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile.provider.ProfilePropertyProviderImpl.getConnectionProfileImpl(ProfilePropertyProviderImpl.java:184)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile.provider.ProfilePropertyProviderImpl.getDataSourceProperties(ProfilePropertyProviderImpl.java:64)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.ConnectionPropertyHandler.getEffectiveProperties(ConnectionPropertyHandler.java:123)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.getEffectiveProperties(OdaConnection.java:826)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.open(OdaConnection.java:240)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:165)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSource.java:224)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:212)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(DataSourceRuntime.java:217)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:407)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:317)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:455)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:145)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:624)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:267)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1939)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:180)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run    (RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
```

has anyone seen this error and can point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

When I had this issue then I tried two things. The first thing solved the error but then I just got to the next error.

The first thing I tried was setting the setenv.sh file to have the following line:
`export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/local/share/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.8/temp/tmpdir -Dorg.eclipse.datatools_workspacepath=/opt/local/share/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.8/temp/tmpdir/workspace_dtp"`

This solution worked after I made the `tmpdir` and the `workspace_dtp` directories in my local tomcat server. This was done in response to the guidance [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Birt_3.7_Migration_Guide#Connection_Profiles).

However, I just got to the next error, which was a connection profile error. I can look into it again if you need. I know how to replicate the issue.

The second thing I tried ended up solving the issue completely and had to do with our report designer selecting the wrong type of datasource in the report design process. See my post on the Eclipse BIRT forums here for the full story: [post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/781961/).

Basically, the report type was set to "JDBC Database Connection for Query Builder" when it should have been set to "JDBC Data Source." See the picture for reference: [image: New Data Source window in Eclipse BIRT New Data Source Wizard]

Answer (score 0):

Here I give you a tip that save me from that pain :
**just launch eclipse with "-clean" option after installing BIRT plugins.**

To be clear, my project was built from BIRT maven dependencies, and so should not use eclipse dependencies to run (except for designing reports), but ... i think there was a conflict somewhere ... especially with org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity_1.2.4.v201202041105.jar

For global understanding, you should follow the migration guide :
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Birt_3.7_Migration_Guide#Connection_Profiles

It helps using a connection profile to externalize datasource parameters.
So it's not required if you define JDBC parameters directly in report design.

Comment: i will take a look, but i am not using 3.7, so there's no migration. i am using 4.2, but will read more on connection profiles.

Comment: your is issues resolved?. I am also facing same issue can u please check the url https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1689369/#msg_1689369

Comment: @Prathyush you can see my new answer with piece of code if that can help you bypassing the connection profile limitations (see forceDataSource)

Answer (score 0):

I used this programmatic way to initialize worskpace directory :

```
@Override
public void initializeEngine() throws BirtException {
    // define eclipse datatools workspace path (required)
    String workspacePath = setDataToolsWorkspacePath();

    // set configuration
    final EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig();
    config.setLogConfig(workspacePath, Level.WARNING);

    // config.setResourcePath(getSqlDriverClassJarPath());

    // startup OSGi framework
    Platform.startup(config); // really needed ?
    IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform
            .createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
    engine = factory.createReportEngine(config);
    engine.changeLogLevel(Level.WARNING);
}

private String setDataToolsWorkspacePath() {
    String workspacePath = System.getProperty(DATATOOLS_WORKSPACE_PATH);
    if (workspacePath == null) {
        workspacePath = FilenameUtils.concat(SystemUtils.getJavaIoTmpDir().getAbsolutePath(), "workspace_dtp");
        File workspaceDir = new File(workspacePath);
        if (!workspaceDir.exists()) {
            workspaceDir.mkdir();
        }
        if (!workspaceDir.canWrite()) {
            workspaceDir.setWritable(true);
        }
        System.setProperty(DATATOOLS_WORKSPACE_PATH, workspacePath);
    }
    return workspacePath;
}
```

I also needed to force datasource parameters at runtime this way :

```
private void generateReportOutput(InputStream reportDesignInStream, File outputFile, OUTPUT_FORMAT outputFormat,
        Map<PARAM, Object> params) throws EngineException, SemanticException {
    // Open a report design
    IReportRunnable design = engine.openReportDesign(reportDesignInStream);

    // Use data-source properties from persistence.xml
    forceDataSource(design);

    // Create RunAndRender task
    IRunAndRenderTask runTask = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);

    // Use data-source from JPA persistence context
    // forceDataSourceConnection(runTask);

    // Define report parameters
    defineReportParameters(runTask, params);

    // Set render options
    runTask.setRenderOption(getRenderOptions(outputFile, outputFormat, params));

    // Execute task
    runTask.run();
}

private void forceDataSource(IReportRunnable runableReport) throws SemanticException {
    DesignElementHandle designHandle = runableReport.getDesignHandle();

    Map<String, String> persistenceProperties = PersistenceUtils.getPersistenceProperties();
    String dsURL = persistenceProperties.get(AvailableSettings.JDBC_URL);
    String dsDatabase = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(dsURL, "/");
    String dsUser = persistenceProperties.get(AvailableSettings.JDBC_USER);
    String dsPass = persistenceProperties.get(AvailableSettings.JDBC_PASSWORD);
    String dsDriver = persistenceProperties.get(AvailableSettings.JDBC_DRIVER);

    SlotHandle dataSources = ((ReportDesignHandle) designHandle).getDataSources();
    int count = dataSources.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        DesignElementHandle dsHandle = dataSources.get(i);
        if (dsHandle != null && dsHandle instanceof OdaDataSourceHandle) {
            // replace connection properties from persistence.xml
            dsHandle.setProperty("databaseName", dsDatabase);
            dsHandle.setProperty("username", dsUser);
            dsHandle.setProperty("password", dsPass);
            dsHandle.setProperty("URL", dsURL);
            dsHandle.setProperty("driverClass", dsDriver);
            dsHandle.setProperty("jarList", getSqlDriverClassJarPath());
            // @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            // List<ExtendedProperty> privateProperties = (List<ExtendedProperty>) dsHandle
            // .getProperty("privateDriverProperties");
            // for (ExtendedProperty extProp : privateProperties) {
            // if ("odaUser".equals(extProp.getName())) {
            // extProp.setValue(dsUser);
            // }
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue

Changing the Data Source type from "JDBC Database Connection for Query Builder" to "JDBC Data Source" solved the problem for me.